# How to politely kill a C++ thread without sharing some stop flags?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to write a test wrapper based on gtest which supports timeouts.

Logically, I would accept a function `f`, create a new thread to run it, and after a certain amount of time has elapsed determine if the thread has finished.

If the thread hasn't finished, then it's timeouted and forced to kill it, but I haven't found a particularly elegant way to kill a thread.

The way many people do it is to have the thread share an atomic variable with an external one, and when you want to kill it, modify that variable and wait for the thread to notice it and self-destruct. But I don't want to have `f` coupled with an external variable (because `f` could be anything and isn't a dead loop who can always check a bool flag).

`Signal` also does not work since it will kill the whole process.

About this, is there any best practice?

Comment: There is no "best practice", because C++ simply does not work this way, on a fundamental level. There is no provision to gratuitously terminate an execution thread, in standard C++, for the elementary reason that this will result in undefined behavior, since none of the objects in automatic scope will have their destructors invoked.

Comment: Forcefully terminating threads is usually a terrible idea. Threads all share the same address space and if you force kill a thread there's no telling what state it has left any shared state in.

Comment: If you want to write a test with timeout  then a viable solution is to spawn a child process. This is also helpful if you want to test `abort()` or other sudden stop scenarios. See http://google.github.io/googletest/reference/assertions.html#death

Comment: `std::jthread` has ways to politely tell a thread to please finish, but its not "kill"

Comment: Arguably to "politely kill" anything is a contradiction to begin with :)

Comment: There's no way to ask another thread to stop running, without the other thread checking whether you asked it to stop running.

Comment: Boost thread has an interrupt feature  https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.interruption but it's still fairly polite

Comment: The best practice is "Don't."

Answer (score 1):

There are only two ways to kill a thread and be reasonably assured that the process that kills the thread will still be able to function:

1. Isolate the thread you want to kill in a different process from the thread that is requesting the kill.
2. Have a method to cooperate with the thread that you want to kill.

There is no third option. It does not exist. Threads can contaminate the process they live in many different ways and if they do not clean things up, there is simply no way that process can continue to make reliable forward progress.